# Resetting the index of a pandas dataframe to overlay separate years on same graph

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, indexing

I'm trying to graph two sets of information on top of each other where data are separated by around a year.

I'm using the following code:

```
ax = df1.loc[df1['Person']==John,['Pts']].expanding().mean().plot()

df2.loc[df2['Person']==John,['Pts']].expanding().mean().plot(ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

Problem: I get a graph showing the expanding mean on two different parts of the graph since the observations are separated by around a year.

Goal: I want them to overlay on top of each other.

Current situation: Two dataframes indexed by a datetime variable 'Date'

df1

```
Date            Person  Pts
Jan 5 2015 2pm  John    10  
Jan 8 2015 4pm  John    22
Jan 5 2015 3pm  Frank   4
Jan 7 2015 10pm Frank   8
```

df2

```
Date            Person  Pts
Jan 3 2016 1pm  John    15  
Jan 9 2016 5pm  John    30
Jan 4 2016 2pm  Frank   12
Jan 8 2016 9pm  Frank   15
```

Desired Output:

df1

```
Index Person  Pts
0     John    10  
1     John    22
0     Frank   4
1     Frank   8
```

df2

```
Date Person  Pts
0    John    15  
1    John    30
0    Frank   12
1    Frank   15
```

All ideas welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem in case anyone else is struggling with a similar issue:

```
grouped1 = df1.groupby('Person', as_index=False)
grouped2 = df2.groupby('Person', as_index=False)
john1 = grouped1.get_group('John').reset_index()
john2 = grouped2.get_group('John').reset_index()
ax = john1['Pts'].expanding().mean().plot()
john2['Pts'].expanding().mean().plot(ax=ax)
plt.show()
```